# Access Derived Class When Only Base Class Header is Included

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to understand if there is a way set an include directive for a base class but also be able to access derived classes that are defined in a different header than the base class. For instance:

In GenericObject.h:

```
class GenericObject { 
    /* whatever - shared properties and methods implemented in .cpp file */ 
}
```

In Ball.h:

```
class Ball : public GenericObject { 
    /* whatever - implementation details are in the .cpp file */
}
```

Now in some other implementation file (let's call it the main.cpp), I have `#include`d `"GenericObject.h"`. In main.cpp, I want to be able to access both the members of the GenericObject class as well as the Ball class and any other derived class of GenericObject. From my trials so far, the compiler won't recognize the Ball identifier if I try to declare it like `Ball * b;` and thus any of the members that belong to its class.

Is this because my `#include`'d `"GenericObject.h"` file is not also linking that there is this derived Ball class for me to access? I can correctly ID and use the Ball class if I `"#include "Ball.h"` but I can't imagine I should include all of the header files of derived classes of the GenericObject class, right?

If I had to take a guess at how this might work, I'd guess that something like a prototype declaration for the Ball class inside the GenericObject class would be a step in the right direction but I'm not sure if a class prototype is even a thing.

Thanks for reading and any feedback everyone!

Comment: You need to learn the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Simplified a translation unit is a single source file and all its included header files. If you don't include the correct header files, the compiler will simply not know the symbols you declare and define in that header file.

Comment: I mentioned that I suspected this was the case but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious or another optimal approach. Thank you though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use any identifier that's not yet described.  This includes any class, whether it derives from a base or not.

It seems to me you are violating [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  If you receive a reference or pointer to a base then you should not be doing anything that requires you know that there is a derived or not.  You should only be using the interface of the base.  Thereby you no longer need to include the headers for derived classes where you're not using something defined only in THEIR interface.

Comment: I think I understand. Even if I was using the base as an interface, I would still need to declare the headers for all of the derived classes, right? If I had 50 different derived classes of the GenericObject class, would I really need 50 `#include` statements for each of those derived classes? I guess that's not really so much what I care about as I'm thinking header files are used so that when the project is recompiled, only files that have changed need to be recompiled. If I have all of those included headers, does that lead to increasing the compile time?

Comment: You only need to include the interfaces you are using.  If you are downcasting to 50 different derived classes, then you will need to include all 50 headers.  If you are not then you do not.  Yes, including 50 headers will increase compile time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. To clarify further, as I'm still a little confused by interface inheritance in C++, can I just `#include` the interface (GenericObject), have the Ball class implement the GenericObject, and then not have to `#include "Ball.h"` this way? Writing it out I don't think that's possible but I want to make sure.

Comment: In that case you will not have to include Ball.h unless you need to refer to Ball by name.  So you can't create one, or use a value of that type.  You can only access it through pointers or references.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know of any good example code that demonstrates accessing an implementation like Ball using pointers and references as you and Mr. R Sahu have suggested?


Are there any suggestions you can make about how to accomplish this scenario using another approach? I know I haven't really posted any source but I imagine this is a common dilemma that OO programmers face. Or perhaps I'm fighting against a bad coding practice?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't imagine I should include all of the header files of derived classes of the `GenericObject` class, right?

If you want to access any class derived from `GenericObject`, other than through a pointer or a reference, you will need to `#include` the header file for them.

If you can get by with using just pointers and references, you don't need to `#include` the header files but you still have to forward declare them.